# Spring-Integration Read files from hdfs

Tags: spring-integration

Can i read files from hdfs using custom scanner in int-file:inbound-channel-adapter that extends from DefaultDirectoryScanner and Implementing org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem as file System ?